# das gesagt zu haben

Tags: infinitive, past-participle

Is this kind of structure used in German?

das gesagt zu haben

*Past participle before an infinitive.*

Can it be used to mean " Having said that " ?

For example:

Ich kann mich nicht erinnern, das gesagt zu haben

I can't remember having said that.

Is this sentence correct?

Comment: Sure. When you are in doubt whether a structure is actually used, you can try a search engine...

Comment: @Alazon - I always try Google to find similar structures but sometimes even a search engine can't give me assurance.

Comment: Well, yes, the attestations still have to be judged. Are they from native speakers etc. But it is obvious that there are reliable attestations among the 30,000 which I get for the string "das gesagt zu haben". On the first page: www.bundesregierung.de "Rede beim Jahresempfang der Klassik Stiftung Weimar" -- it doesn't get better than that ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a correct sentence. But it doesn't express "Having said that".
It's more like when you're pretty sure, but you want to phrase it carefully because your memory can deceive you. Another example would be "Ich denke nicht diese Person schon einmal gesehen zu haben". I would not use this kind of structure if you are absolutely sure about something.

Comment: Of course, this structure is also used in English to express a certain degree of doubt. I just wanted to convey the same meaning in German. I don't think I have ever seen this person means I'm not sure whether I have (have not) seen him/her before. I may or may not.

Answer (score 1):

> Ich kann mich nicht erinnern, das gesagt zu haben.
> I can't remember having said that.

Yes, the sentence is correct and the two sentences are adequate translations of each other.

*Having said that*, there is also another way of using "having said that" in English (like in this very sentence), for which the translation is NOT adequate at all. In this case:

> Das gesagt, ...
> Und, nachdem das gesagt ist, ...
> Davon abgesehen ...

would be better (more idiomatic) translations. The above sentence, for instance:

> Davon abgesehen gibt es aber auch noch eine andere Verwendung von ...

Comment: I think Das gesagt, .... is precisely translated as " that being said " and not having said that. That being said in English means (however, although)